# document.body is null in window IE 8 with jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a strange error only happen in Window 7 and IE 8.

I use jQuery in a html. I double click and launch the html in IE. It will show error document.body is null inside the jquery library in the first time. But the error will disappear after i reload the page. The html just loading the jquery js file only and no other js or css.

Didn't happen in other browser.

Comment: Have you validated your markup?  *Usually* that's the error in cases like this, give it a try here: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Yeah, and show the jQuery code you are using

Comment: @conqenator: yes...i found that this problem is occured when i have a external script loaded which include code $(doucment).ready.

Comment: Are you sure the page is not cached ? Try loading the page with a url parameter like `http://your.domain.here/thepage.ext?1234`

Comment: @Gaby: This only happen when in local.

Comment: I am having the same error with Mootools, and it only occurs in IE8 / Windows 7.

Comment: >>Thomas Hunter , it only happen when test in local folder. No problem when put on server. Seen a bug on IE

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the external script is loaded before the document body can be defined.
So you can just place the portion of your script that has `$(document).ready` at the end of `<body></body>`.